# Get document data from Firebase Firestore in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

after not finding anything online, I decided to write here. I need to get all the document in the `/user/uid` collection in Node JS. When I use the Firebase code it replies like this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

Please help me!

PS: I don't want to use Firebase Admin SDK and await.

"Full" code

```
var express = require('express');

const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const { getDatabase, ref, get, child, set, onValue} = require("firebase/database");
const { getFirestore, collection, getDoc, doc} = require("firebase/firestore");

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to the database service

var app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5050

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('This is my demo project')
});

const db = getDatabase();
const firestore = getFirestore();


const document = getDoc(doc(collection(firestore, 'users'), "BW5kylV6rtZXtYibpKGc2m1asRm1"));
  
console.log(document);

//Response: "Promise {<pending>}""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase method calls are asynchronous. So for both the Admin SDK or the JS SDK you **have to deal with the asynchronicity**, either by using `then` or by using `async/await`.

If you receive `Promise {<pending>}` it is because the asynchronous method `getDoc` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and this promise is not fulfilled, but is still pending.

So you need to dive into the documentation on how to use Promises... or the `async/await` keywords.

In your case, the following will do the trick:

```
getDoc(doc(collection(firestore, 'users'), "BW5kylV6rtZXtYibpKGc2m1asRm1"))
.then(snap => {
   console.log(snap.data())
})
```

However, if you write this code for running on a Node server you own, I would recommend to use the Admin SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! The code you gave me works. I wanted to ask you one last thing, why do you advise me to use the Admin SDK, keeping the credentials is no less secure? I have to perform mostly read-only operations on Firestore and Realtime DB. Thanks so much

Comment: Glad that I could help you. To answer your question I have myself a question: You mention that you use Node.js. Where does your code run? On a server you own?

Comment: I need to build APIs that take the values from the database. For now I hosto it locally.

Comment: Ok, so you could also use one or more [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). In any case, whether you use your own server or a Cloud Fucntion, the recommended SDK in this case is the Admin SDK. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) for more details.